# Divide rows by conditional row sums

Tags: r, division

Consider the following matrix:

`m <- cbind(c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r1","r2","r3","r4"),c(3,2,5,2,5,2,6,4),c(4,3,5,3,7,4,6,7))`

For each row I want to divide the row sum with their conditional row sum. That is, for all the rows with the name "r1", I want to divide their row sum with the row sum of all rows with the name "r1". Thus, for the first row that is "(3+4)/(3+4+5+7)".

And the same for "r2", "r3" and "r3". So for instance for the second row, the calculation is "(2+3)/(2+3+2+4)".

How do I do that in R?

Comment: Why do you have it as matrix? It coerces everything to character

Comment: Is it better that it is a data.frame?

Comment: Well, you can't have more than one types in a matrix so you need to make it a data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create your data as a data.frame rather than a matrix so that the numeric columns are not coerced to character. (could also use first two lines from sotos' answer to convert to data.frame from matrix if you've already created a matrix)

```
df <- data.frame(row_id = c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r1","r2","r3","r4"),
                v1 = c(3,2,5,2,5,2,6,4),
                v2 = c(4,3,5,3,7,4,6,7))
```

Now if you convert your data.frame to a data.table with `setDT`, you can do this operation using data.table grouping (`by = row_id` sets the groups)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, ratio := (v1 + v2)/sum(v1 + v2), by = row_id]

df
#    row_id v1 v2     ratio
# 1:     r1  3  4 0.3684211
# 2:     r2  2  3 0.4545455
# 3:     r3  5  5 0.4545455
# 4:     r4  2  3 0.3125000
# 5:     r1  5  7 0.6315789
# 6:     r2  2  4 0.5454545
# 7:     r3  6  6 0.5454545
# 8:     r4  4  7 0.6875000
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution after we tidy your data,

```
df <- data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.numeric)
df$new <- df$X2 + df$X3

with(df, ave(new, X1, FUN = function(i)i / sum(i)))
#[1] 0.3684211 0.4545455 0.4545455 0.3125000 0.6315789 0.5454545 0.5454545 0.6875000
```

Comment: `ave(rowSums(df[,-1]), df$X1, FUN = function(i) i / sum(i))`

Answer (score 1):

```
m <- cbind(c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r1","r2","r3","r4"),c(3,2,5,2,5,2,6,4),c(4,3,5,3,7,4,6,7))

require(dplyr)



m %>%  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(V4 = as.numeric(V2) + as.numeric(V3)) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(conditional_sum = sum(V4)) %>%  
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(calculation = V4/conditional_sum) 

# A tibble: 8 x 6
# V1    V2    V3       V4 conditional_sum calculation
# <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 r1    3     4         7              19       0.368
# 2 r2    2     3         5              11       0.455
# 3 r3    5     5        10              22       0.455
# 4 r4    2     3         5              16       0.312
# 5 r1    5     7        12              19       0.632
# 6 r2    2     4         6              11       0.545
# 7 r3    6     6        12              22       0.545
# 8 r4    4     7        11              16       0.688
```